# Not able to create a Foreign Constraint in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Here is the script I am trying to run

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
`store_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`store_name` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
`store_user` INT NOT NULL,
`store_address` INT NOT NULL,
`store_type` INT NOT NULL,
`created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_address` (
`address_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`address_line_1` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
`address_line_2` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
`address_line_3` VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`locality` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`pincode` CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
`latitude` DECIMAL(8,6) NULL,
`longitude` DECIMAL(9,6) NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_STR_STR_ADR`
FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`)
REFERENCES `store` (`store_address`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I get this error - `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`
No clue what is wrong with the DDL

Comment: I am guessing foreign key is backwards; it should be in store, referencing address. It should still allow it though, unless maybe you already have data which would violate the constraint...ah, to implement it that way, there needs to be an index on `store.store_address`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues: 
1. use unsigned int for the primary keys (Edit: this is a good idea but was not the problem)
2. the store.store address must be a key in the store table in order to use it in a foreign key constraint in the store_address table

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
 `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `store_name` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
 `store_user` INT NOT NULL,
 `store_address` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `store_type` INT NOT NULL,
 `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
 KEY (`store_address`)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_address` (
 `address_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `address_line_1` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
 `address_line_2` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
 `address_line_3` VARCHAR(1024) NULL,
 `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `locality` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `pincode` CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 `latitude` DECIMAL(8,6) NULL,
 `longitude` DECIMAL(9,6) NULL,
 `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `updated_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`address_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_STR_STR_ADR` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_address`)
 )ENGINE = InnoDB;
```